# Can't apply background on menu container

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have container with width of 100% and inside of it i have a menu. When i want to apply background color to menu container nothing happens, its killing me i cant figure it out.
It works when i apply display inline-block on it but why would i need to display it differently its only a container 100% width

```
menu {
    width: 100%;
    background: #333;
}

.menu > ul {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.menu > ul > li {
    float: left;
    background: #e9e9e9;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.menu > ul > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1.5em 3em;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: 0 none;
}

.menu > ul > li > ul {
    display: none;
    background: #333;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
    left: 0;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
}

.menu > ul > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

and this is my html

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      <ul>
        This is also mega menu
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Who are we?</a>
      <ul>
        This is mega menu
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</li></a>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</li></a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

also when i try to float my UL to right nothing happens. Did i mess up my display: in any element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your LI elements are floated. In this case, container will have a height of 0 pixels. You need to clear the container (.menu) first. There's also a slight error on the MENU element - you forgot to add the DOT .menu (to be a class, as in your html code).

To clear floats, read this > https://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/

```
.menu:before,
.menu:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.menu:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

A working scenario, on jsfiddle, here > jsfiddle.net/4pgvzxs0/

Comment: Wow clearfix was solution, didnt even think about that, thank you very much! Is it ok for my LI to be floated, is there any other solution or is it just fine like that. Thanks in advance

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve, or the way elements interact with the screen, depending on it. Float is ok. Inline-block could be another viable solution, but if I were you I would've chosen floats.